# Google Calendar API Authentication for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am getting the following error when attempting to Insert a new calendar to the user who is currently logged in. Users are able to log in and register but attempting to add a new calendar gives us this error.

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Insufficient Permission [403]
Errors [
Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]
]
```

The error occurs at the execute of the following code:

```
CalendarService googlecalender = new CalendarService(await (new GoogleAuthentication()).GetInitializer());
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.Summary = "sampleCalendar";
calendar.Id = "_Sample";
calendar.Kind = "calendar#calendar";

var calendarRequest = googlecalender.Calendars.Insert(calendar);
var result = calendarRequest.Execute();
```

I have modified the google authentication to the following:

```
var authenInfo = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions();

authenInfo.Scope.Add("openid");
authenInfo.Scope.Add("profile");
authenInfo.Scope.Add("email");
authenInfo.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
authenInfo.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
authenInfo.Scope.Add(YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube);
authenInfo.Scope.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);
authenInfo.Scope.Add(CalendarService.Scope.CalendarReadonly);

authenInfo.ClientId = "CLIENTID";
authenInfo.ClientSecret = "CLIENTSECRET";

authenInfo.Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider();

app.UseGoogleAuthentication(authenInfo);
```

and the GoogleAuthentication class is this:

```
    public GoogleAuthentication()
    {
        ClientSecret = new ClientSecrets();
        ClientSecret.ClientSecret = "CLIENTSECRET";
        ClientSecret.ClientId = "CLIENTID";
        Scope = new[] {
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
                YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,
                CalendarService.Scope.Calendar
            };
    }

    private async void Authorize()
    {

        Credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            ClientSecret,
            Scope,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
            );
    }
    public async Task<BaseClientService.Initializer> GetInitializer()
    {
        if (Credential == null)
            Authorize();
        else if (Credential.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
        {
            Boolean tokenRefreshed = await Credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }

        return new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = Credential,
            ApplicationName = Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationName
        };
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually enabled access to this particular API for your project? See: `https://console.developers.google.com/project/[your project name]/apiui/apiview/calendar/overview`

Comment: 403 is an authentication failure.  oauth2 involves a human doing authorisation (usually via a web browser) and the program storing an authorisation token (usually to file, and in addition to the id and secret).  I'm not much of a C# person so I can't tell if you've completed this whole loop, esp. the token.